# Is a grid or p2p architecture a subset of a broker architecture?

Tags: architecture, software, distributed-computing

Is a grid or p2p architecture a subset of a broker architecture?

what are the key features that make these similar or distinct?

Comment: Can you provide working definitions for people who may not be familiar with one or the other or under different names?

Comment: I'm not precisely sure - I think that's implicit in the question. However, a broker architecture is an architecture with a client, server and a middleman that registers clients and servers. A grid architecture I think is any kind of distributed architecture ?

Answer (score 1):

In a [peer-to-peer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer-to-peer) architecture, all peers are supposed to be on the same level. There is no distinction between `clients`, `servers`, or other special roles.

`Broker` as integration function is a more central role in hub-and-spoke architectures. The broker typically maps and routes messages. The broker may be part of the central middleware or it can be attached as a separate component to a messaging system.

A [grid architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grid_computing) is a distributed set of nodes or systems which collaborate to serve a common goal. Typically, there is some central system which distributes sub-tasks and collects the results. The nodes may be computers or they may be parts of microchips. Look for "[Systolic Arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systolic_array)".